# mongodb: restore replicaset after kubernetes scaling down

Tags: mongodb

I configured a replicatset correctly.

After having scaled down mongodb kubernetes pods, replicat set truned out to invalid status:

```
> rs.status();
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Our replica set config is invalid or we are not a member of it",
        "code" : 93,
        "codeName" : "InvalidReplicaSetConfig"
}
```

My configuration is:

```json
> rs.config();
{
        "_id" : "rs0",
        "version" : 3,
        "term" : 2,
        "protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1),
        "writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault" : true,
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "host" : "mongors-0.mongors-service.hes-all.svc:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "host" : "mongors-1.mongors-service.hes-all.svc:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                }
        ],
        "settings" : {
                "chainingAllowed" : true,
                "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 2000,
                "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
                "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000,
                "catchUpTimeoutMillis" : -1,
                "catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis" : 30000,
                "getLastErrorModes" : {

                },
                "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
                        "w" : 1,
                        "wtimeout" : 0
                },
                "replicaSetId" : ObjectId("626fb63f211511c4dcf938ac")
        }
}
```

configuration details seem right, but when I run `rs.initiate`, or `rs.reconfig(cfg)`:

```json
> rs.reconfig(config);
{
        "topologyVersion" : {
                "processId" : ObjectId("6347bdffe3c3303e6f325b9a"),
                "counter" : NumberLong(1)
        },
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "New config is rejected :: caused by :: replSetReconfig should only be run on a writable PRIMARY. Current state REMOVED;",
        "code" : 10107,
        "codeName" : "NotWritablePrimary"
}

> rs.initiate();
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "already initialized",
        "code" : 23,
        "codeName" : "AlreadyInitialized"
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what does `rs.status()` show?

Comment: You can see `rs.status()` output at the begining of post... Shortly: `"errmsg" : "Our replica set config is invalid or we are not a member of it"`. See on post to see full response.

Comment: have you attempted? : rs.reconfig(config,{force:true});

Comment: It's yet failing. The immadiate output is `{ok: 1}`, but after that, `rs.status()` is still getting me that `"codeName" : "InvalidReplicaSetConfig"`...